# Adword: Encountered flash error - ad cannot use mouse tracking

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, google-ads-api

Trying to create a banner ad as a one-off project for a client.  I am using Flash Builder / AS 3 and with my simple hello world example.  Google Adwords rejects the add with: **Encountered flash error - ad cannot use mouse tracking.**

**I Have not been able to figure out what I am doing that signals to Adwords that I am mouse tracking.**  Follows is my simple mxml file:  (the handleClick is to adhear to their clickTAG specification)

Thanks!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="336" minHeight="280" width="336" height="280" includeInLayout="true" click="handleClick(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function handleClick(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void {
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG),"_blank");    
            }   

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible that whatever automated analysis that Google does on the ads submitted is being confused by the Flex framework. You could try creating an ActionScript project instead of Flex project in Flash builder and see if that makes any difference.

If you use an ActionScript project you won't be able to use MXML for creating the ad, but you might not really even want to drag in the Flex framework, since it takes a while to load (the first time at least).

Comment: Thanks man! That worked.  Man it was very hard for me to get any guidance on this question anywhere else.